# C# Google Calendar API - not valid Deadline calendar format

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

When I want to execute the event, it doesn't execute (which means that the event is not in my calendar), and I get the following error:

`System.FormatException: The "Deadline calendar" google-api-dotnet-client/1.42.0.0 (gzip) value format is not valid.`

Any idea how to fix this? It worked some month ago and I just noticed that it doesn't work anymore.

Some code example:

```
public static CalendarService getCalendarService
{
   get
   {
      var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret },
      new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
         return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "Deadline calendar" });
    }
};

var ev = new Event
{
   ICalUID = project.RefId,
   Description = project.Description,
   Summary = string.Format("'{0} ({1})' project deadline", project.Name, project.RefId),
   Location = project.Location,
   Start = new EventDateTime { TimeZone = "MST", DateTime = project.EndDate.Value.Date },
   End = new EventDateTime { TimeZone = "MST", DateTime = project.EndDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1) },
   Attendees = attendees.Select(x => new EventAttendee() { Email = x.Email, Organizer = (x.Id == project.Responsible ? true : false) }).ToList()
};

var projectEvent = getCalendarService.Events.Insert(ev, "primary");
projectEvent.SendNotifications = true;
projectEvent.Execute();
```

Comment: please post exact code which results in error you mention

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that from the post. Now edited!

Comment: please include the code for getCalendarService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was the format of the application name. I used characters which aren't allowed in this string, like: "á, ő".

Thanks your anwers anyway! :)